# Notepad++ showing replacement value in searched lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using NP++ and it's regular expression replacement capabilities, which are of course, very pleasant to work with. However, I wonder if there's a way within NP++ (using the Style Configurator perhaps?) that will show not only what it **found** using the regular expression, but also what it will **replace**, once it's found it.

For example, I'm searching lines of text that (amongst other things) contains an email address and I want to remove everything, bar the email address. I'm using the following regular expression:

```
^.* (\w{1,}\.\w{1,}@MyEmailAddressDomain\.com).*$
```

and I'm replacing it simply with

```
$1
```

as I want nothing but the email address. (*I appreciate that this isn't the best "email lookup" to use, but it suffices for this particular instance, and isn't the crux of the question anyway.*)

NP++ highlights every line that contains an email address in light grey and as per the expression; but I'm looking for is an **additional** highlighting syntax that will show what the "$1" will replace, in this case, the email address within each line, to the point that whilst the entire line is highlighted in light grey (to signify that the regular expression has "hit" this line as being one that it's concerned with), the actual replacement value is (for example) is in bold, or red, or just some other color?

Online regular expression testing sites (such as https://regex101.com/) show this very nicely, so I was just wondering if anyone knows a way of producing the same within NP++?

Comment: Your question as is here is off-topic by this rule: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." So I voted to close it.

Comment: OP edited accordingly

Comment: There's no such functionality on npp or plugin! The closest you can get is http://nppregexhelper.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @JorgeCampos - thank you, that would certainly help